# Rotating one view and leaving another unmoved in Swift / Xcode for iOS on orientation change

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, size-classes, screen-rotation

I'm writing an iPhone app. For most of the scenes on our storyboard the default behaviour when the phone changes from portrait orientation to landscape orientation is fine. I.e. this is the layout change we want:

[image: Portrait view] [image: Landscape view]

But for one of the scenes in the storyboard I do not want this layout change. Instead I want this:

[image: Portrait view] [image: Different landscape view]

I am confused about how to achieve the latter layout change. I can use size classes to ensure that the 100 pixels gap for the toolbar swaps from the bottom (portrait) to the right (landscape), but I cannot work out how to constrain the toolbar correctly, especially because the rotation needs to happen in code, e.g.

```swift
switch (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft, UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
    self.toolbarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(3 * M_PI_2))
    // Reposition toolbarView into space to the right of the content's view
    break
default:
    self.toolbarView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    break
}
```

What should I do to reposition the toolbar correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Layout constraints constrain the `frame` of the given view. Let's see what the documentation says about the interplay between the `frame` and `transform` properties:

> WARNING
>   If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.
>
> ...
>
> if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame

So you cannot do this via AutoLayout. You have to use `center` and `bounds`, and do positioning from code:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.toolbarView.center = ...
    self.toolbarView.bounds = ...
}
```

Comment: Looks good. How do I turn off AutoLayout for the item so that the `center` and `bounds` manipulations you suggest stick?

Comment: If you're using storyboards/xibs, make sure you check the "remove at build time" checkbox on the toolbar's constraints. This lets you position the toolbar from code (because there will be no constraints on the toolbar at runtime), and also silences the interface builder warnings (because in the interface builder, the necessary constraints are still there).

Comment: self.toolbarView is actually a compound UIView with subviews of its own (one another UIView with some text and an image, and one's a UIToolbar). Having committed to overriding layoutSubviews to position self.toolbarView can I still use auto layout on its subviews or do I need to lay them all out by manipulating centers and bounds?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use autolayout on the contained views.

Comment: Auto-layout of the subview tree doesn't seem to work (the leaves think their superview's have width zero) and the UIToolbar buttons do not fire their action unless it is all auto layout. Thanks for your help - this is a nightmare.